# Browsers freeze for a moment while renderring views in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I am still a beginner in **GWT** . Firstly I write a sample project and run it . And open with browser giving url by **Development Mode** of my Eclipse IDE. At this time , I noticed that my browser was stopped just a few seconds and I can't do anythings on my browser . If I have some other pages are loading to open , they also stop loading . I think in this time browsers will download **JavaScript files** these need to show my page. That is worse thing for me .

By using **RPC** , I retrieve many datas from my database and try to render to my view page. That may also happen stop for a moment to my browser. So , I had add a ***Gif image*** in my web-page and press some button to retrieve data and try to render my view page. Supprisingly , this ***Gif image*** also stop animation. Why has this situation happend with **GWT** project ?

I am testing it in **localhost**. Can I avoid it ? Any suggestions ? Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Development mode (localhost) is very different from the production mode. It is many times slower, and it requires a lot of memory. This is why your browser freezes. You can:

1. Try a different browser. You may have a better performance on your system.
2. Add memory to your computer.
3. Optimize your code. There are many ways to do it. As a first step you need to understand what causes a problem: processing data or rendering of a page.
4. Finally, deploy your code to the production environment and check if you experience the same problems.

Comment: yes sir ! you are right ! I agree with production environment.I also face this problem just in development mode. Thanks for useful knowledges. And I had deployed using GAE , that was not occured browser freezing.